# Exact fast factorial computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, factorial, integers

For calculating a power, i.e. $a^b$, well-known fast algorithm exists, based on bitwise decomposition of $b$ and sequential squaring of $a$. Are there similar fast algorithms for calculating a factorial? Most fast factorial algorithms I found focus on optimal reordering of variable-complexity bigint multiplications, but not on reducing the number of bigint operations. The only one I found reduces multiplications twice using a recurrent way of evaluating the sequence $A_n=n\times(N+1-n)$, of course by the price of using several additions instead of a multiplication. Is it possible to calculate $N!$ using $O(\log N)$ operations, are there such algorithms?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How about using Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi That's too easy :-) Changed the header.

Comment: Do you want to claculate $N!$ exactly or $N!$ modulo some $M$  ? For the latter there is no known efficient method (such a method would allow efficient prime factorization and would make RSA useless).